# How do you insert '<' sign in mediawiki?

Tags: mediawiki

How do you insert '<' sign in mediawiki?
It's got to be simple, this is driving me nuts....
I've tried \l, it doesn't work

Comment: No, sometimes, I'm so stupid, I forget the common sense things.... Thanks!

Comment: What is the problem with using the character `<` as it is? Works for [me](http://xn--ssongsmat-v2a.nu/ssm/Test), and in [Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Vergleichszeichen&action=edit), and would be less confusing to non technical editors

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
&lt;
```

Should work.

Answer (score 0):

All of these work for me on a MediaWiki 1.24.1 installation:

```
* <
* <nowiki><</nowiki>
* &lt;
```

[image]

Whereas

```
* <li>
* <nowiki><li></nowiki>
* &lt;li&gt;
```

gives

[image]